# How do you get the string value of a MongoID using PHP?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

After doing an insert I want to pass the object to the client using json_encode(). The problem is, the _id value is not included.

```
$widget = array('text' => 'Some text');

$this->mongo->db->insert($widget);


If I echo $widget['_id'] the string value gets displays on the screen, but I want to do something like this:

$widget['widgetId'] = $widget['_id']->id;


So I can do json_encode() and include the widget id:

echo json_encode($widget);
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Believe this is what you're after.

```
$widget['_id']->{'$id'};
```

Something like this.

```
$widget = array('text' => 'Some text');
$this->mongo->db->insert($widget);
$widget['widgetId'] = $widget['_id']->{'$id'};
echo json_encode($widget);
```

Comment: Reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php. I'd prefer the (string) typecast below myself but at the time of the question I was using the method outlined in the docs.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use:

```
(string)$widget['_id']
```

Answer (score 5):

correct way is use ObjectId from MongoDB:

```
function getMongodbIDString($objectId){
    $objectId = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($objectId);
    return $objectId->jsonSerialize()['$oid'];
}
```

and do not cast the objectId like `(string) $row['_id']` or `$row->_id->{'$oid'}`

Comment: thanks for giving this code. no other code works except this...once thanks alot.

Comment: @Dhanunjaya, nice, try use Doctrine ODM, it handle all this stuff

Answer (score 2):

I used something similar:

```
(string)$widget->_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it is working fine for me...  
 $filter=['_id' => $row->_id]; and $filter you can pass to deleteOne and findOne function

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar if object:

```
$widget->_id->{'$oid'}
```

or

```
(string)$widget->_id
```

or array :

```
$widget['id']->{'$oid'}
(string)$widget['_id']
```