# How do I get the ID from mongodb with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to get the ID from mongodb to modify and delete user from a simple CRUD app with PHP and vue.js using axios

When I insert any user, I get this id.

```
{ "$oid": "5a8fd1ef1233610e40007667" }
```

I just need the ID that mongodb generate itself.

```
"5a8fd1ef1233610e40007667"
```

I'm using POST to get the ID and this is what I get when I use var_dump()

```
string(15) "[object Object]"
```

¿Any idea of how to get that ID? I've already tried several things, I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the string value of a MongoID using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861332/how-do-you-get-the-string-value-of-a-mongoid-using-php)

Answer (score 3):

See the [The MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php) class.

> In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique _id field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the _id field, the driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field.

specifically `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId::__toString`, which returns the hexidecimal representation of the ObjectId. You can invoke `__toString` by casting the ObjectId to string, for example:

```
$stringID = (string)$objectID;
```

You do not need to create the ObjectID when you insert the record, for example (based on your comment)

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
$doc  = [ 'firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname ];
$bulk->insert($doc);
$result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk);
var_dump($result);
```

The mongo driver will create and set the '_id' field, `insert` takes the array by reference and can alter it.

Comment: I insert the id in database using BulkWrite.

    $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    $doc = [ '_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID, 'firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname ];

    $bulk->insert($doc);

This generate a random number of 24 letters and digits.

Comment: Please see the updated answer showing how to perform this correctly.

Comment: You're right, I don't need to create the ObjectID. I did it and in echo I get string(0) "" .

Comment: Please read up on `BulkWrite`, ensure you are calling `executeBulkWrite`, and check it's return value. It seems like `BulkWrite` is not what you are looking for.

Comment: However, this doesn't answer my question. Your talking about insert, and my question is about delete and update. I still get the `[object Object]`. I've tried it to handle it without vue.js and works perfectly. I guess, the "problem" is when vue.js and mongodb works togheter.
Either way, I thank you for your replys.